# Kamailio 4.4 seturi Only Accepts Explicit Strings?

Tags: proxy, sip, kamailio

I've been working at implementing a simple serial forking described in the TM module's documentation (the Q values are stored as a priority weight in a mysql table) where my proxy is querying a database to determine to what domain to forward to.

I've verified through extensive use of xlog that a variable I'm using to build the new URI to use with seturi is getting everything correctly. I use an append_branch call in a subsequent while loop iterating over my sql query results, which doesn't have any problems with taking a very similarly formatted parameter. However, when I go to restart Kamailio it simply gripes at me that a string is expected. The line it corresponds to from console is just the seturi call. I've tried casting as a string, but that doesn't seem to be part of 4.4 (or my syntax is wrong).

I've thought about building the URI strings and storing into avp, but I suspect I'd have the same problem.

For reference, this is what I'm doing:

```
$var(basedest) = "sip:" + $var(number) + "@" + $(dbr(destination=>[0,0]))+ ":" + $var(port);
seturi($var(basedest));
```

And what it's outputting when trying to load the config:

```
<core> [cfg.y:3368]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file //etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 570, column 9-22: syntax error
<core> [cfg.y:3371]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file //etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 570, column 23: bad argument, string expected
```

Naturally, when I put $var(basedest) in double quotes, it's literally interpreted as a string. Single quotes behave similarly. Is there something I can do to work around this? When I feed it an explicit hardcoded string, it's happy as a can be and the routing works fine. When I try to do something very simple like the above, it gets upset. If possible, I'd like to avoid updating as I initially grabbed Kamailio from the yum repo.

Thanks in advance - this has been bugging me a good while.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, not a new problem. I ended up finding out what I can do to work around it.

For reference, seturi and $ru pseudo variable refer to the same thing. So basically you'd just do:

```
$var(mynewru) = "sip:user@domain:5060";
$ru = $var(mynewru);
```

This would achieve the same thing I was originally attempting to do before based on the TM module's documentation. For serial forking, issuing some number of append_branch calls is fine.